# One DC stopped syncronizing. Error in logs

Tags: cassandra

We started seeing this error in the logs. At the same time the only node in the DC "datacenter_spark" stopped syncronizing to the DC "datacenter-prod".

The columns from the error message point to a table that we have, but comparing the node on both DC it has the same columns.

What is causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

**Error:**

```
2021-07-20 07:54:03,927 ERROR [ReadStage-1] AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 run Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-1,5,main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [color, icon_image_file, name, type] is not a subset of [icon_image_file name type]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns$Serializer.encodeBitmap(Columns.java:565)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns$Serializer.serializeSubset(Columns.java:497)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody(UnfilteredSerializer.java:230)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:137)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:125)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:137)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:79)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:307)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:180)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:176)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:353)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommandVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadCommandVerbHandler.java:50)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:165)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:137)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Nodetool status:**

```
Datacenter: datacenter-prod
===========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.164.0.23   143.14 GiB  256          100.0%            e7e2a38a-d4f3-4758-a345-73fcffe26035  rack1
UN  10.164.0.24   146.79 GiB  256          100.0%            0c18b8e4-5ca2-4fb5-9e8c-663b74909fbb  rack1
UN  10.164.0.58   151.03 GiB  256          100.0%            547c0746-72a8-4fec-812a-8b926d2426ae  rack1
Datacenter: datacenter_spark
============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.16.0.179  140.57 GiB  256          100.0%            790cef99-9234-4b2d-8389-c4407ed8cb9b  rack1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that there is a mismatch between the table schema and the data on disk.

You'll need to check for schema agreement across all nodes in the cluster. If you've recently made schema changes, check the current table definition versus what's on disk.

One possibility is that something went wrong when you tried to drop a column and the entry is missing from the `system_schema.dropped_columns` table. If this is the case, you will need to temporarily add the column back to the table with the same CQL data type then drop the column. Cheers!